# Test only project in maven, is it acceptable?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation

I want to write automation code on a web application which is being build and deployed separately (in a different maven project).

The test suite is expected to run selenium tests on the web application.

If I am to create a default maven project

Say using
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

I end up having the below folder structure

```
E:\AUTOMATION\EXAMPLE\MY-APP  
└───src  
    ├───main  
    │   └───java  
    │       └───com  
    │           └───mycompany  
    │               └───app  
    └───test  
        └───java  
            └───com  
                └───mycompany  
                    └───app
```

But here where should I start crafting my test code?

Comment: If this module is only for testing, it doesn't matter where you put the classes.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey, Yes I guess so. But I was after the best practice to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com/mycompany/app` is only there for an example. 
Replace all that with whatever package name is suitable for you.

If you will only run test code with `mvn test`,
and the project doesn't need to export any code to use elsewhere,
then you can put all your code under `src/test/java`.

If you do have some code that will be an end product to package as a jar and use elsewhere,
then put the public API code in `src/main/java` and keep only the tests in `src/test/java`.

Comment: Thanks @janos. I was using the default project names to explain the question. Yes, I will only run code with mvn test, and it will not be exported.